# Background-css feature in jQuery for radial-gradients

Tags: jquery, css

I'm new to this Forum and I'm not native speaker of this language. I will still try my very best to explain the problem.

I created a spot with the .css feature in jQuery, all worked fine until I stumbled about the background: 'radial-gradient...' feature. I do not know the right syntax of this feature.

I first tried:

```
'background-image': 'radial-gradient (closest corner at 35% 35%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 5%, rgba('+ color +','+ opacity +') 20%)
```

but it didn't work as expected. As I looked in Firebug, the background-image code weren't shown.

My whole jQuery function looks like this:

```
function spots(spotCount) {
    var spotCount = spotCount;
    for (i = 0; i < spotCount; i++) {
        var opacity = '0.' + randomNumber(2, 5);
        var color = randomNumber(0, 255) + ',' + randomNumber(0, 255) + ',' + randomNumber(0, 255);
        var size = randomNumber(20, 30);
        var top = randomNumber(0, (($('#wrap')).height() - size));
        var left = randomNumber(-100, (980 - size + 100));
        $('<div id="spot' + i + '"></div>').appendTo('#header .width');
        $('#spot' + i).css({
            position: 'absolute',
            top: top + 'px',
            left: left + 'px',
            'z-index': '-100',
            width: size + 'px',
            height: size + 'px',
            'border-radius': size + 'px',
            border: 'rgba(' + color + ',' + opacity + ') solid 1px',
            background: 'radial-gradient (closest-corner at 35% 35%, rgba(255,255,255,'+ opacity +'),rgba(' + color + ',' + opacity + '))'
        });
    }
```

Also I need the -webkit- syntax for safari 5.1.

Can anybody tell me the right syntax?

Many thanks in advance.

The jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g99et0yq/1/

As you can see, the spots are emty.

Comment: Create a fiddle please..

Comment: Check this tool: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: One common practice on this site is to share a jsfiddle. Go on http://jsfiddle.net/, write your code in the appropriate boxes (the JS in the JS box, the CSS in the CSS box, etc), then click "run" to run the code and see the page in the bottom-right box. When you’re done, click on "save" and copy the page URL in your question. This helps everybody understand your code in context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by myself!

jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/g99et0yq/10/

The HTML:

```
<div id="header" style="height:300px;">
    <div class="width" style="width:300px;">

    </div>
</div>
```

The js:

```
function randomNumber(minimal, maximal)
{
    return(minimal + parseInt(Math.random() * (maximal - minimal + 1)));
}

function spots(spotCount) {
    var spotCount = spotCount;
    for (i = 0; i < spotCount; i++) {
        var opacity = '0.' + randomNumber(2, 5);
        var color = randomNumber(0, 255) + ',' + randomNumber(0, 255) + ',' + randomNumber(0, 255);
        var size = randomNumber(20, 30);
        var top = randomNumber(0, (($('#header')).height() - size));
        var left = randomNumber(-100, (980 - size + 100));
        $('<div id="spot' + i + '"></div>').appendTo('#header .width');
        $('#spot' + i).css({
            position: 'absolute',
            top: top + 'px',
            left: left + 'px',
            'z-index': '-100',
            width: size + 'px',
            height: size + 'px',
            'border-radius': size + 'px',
            border: 'none',
            'background-color':  'rgba('+ color +','+ opacity +')'
        }).addClass('spotgloss');
    }
}

spots(10);
```

The css:

```
.spotgloss {
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(35% 35%, circle, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 35%); 
background: radial-gradient(circle at 35% 35%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 35%);
}
```

Comment: Please do not circumvent the quality filter by formatting the word "jsfiddle" as code. List the specific code changes that you made instead.